# get distinct field and their count mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table like

```
A       B        C 
..................
1       2        a
1       3        b
1       4        a
```

I want the result of query which could give resullt as their distinct value and count 
Eg. for above table

```
result

`{a 2 , b 1}`
```

I am using `sql 5.6`.

I tried using `GROUP_CONCAT(C) group by A`.
But I cant store their `count` this way.

Comment: I guess you already tried `select c, count(*) from t group by c`, right?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a subquery to get your `COUNT` and distinct `c` values. From that you can make your `GROUP_CONCAT`:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (c char(1));
INSERT INTO foo VALUES ('a'),('a'),('b');
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(c,' ',countc))
FROM (SELECT c, count(*) as countc FROM foo GROUP BY c) sub;

a 2,b 1
```

[sqldiffle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3bdf57/6)

Answer (score 1):

First group to get the counters and then use group_concat():

```
select 
  concat('{', group_concat(concat(t.C, ' ', t.counter)), '}') result
from (                           
  select C, count(*) counter
  from tablename
  group by C
) t
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tbkQhDCfSFBsuVce7jtmFL/0).
Results:

```
| result    |
| --------- |
| {a 2,b 1} |
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need something like the following query:

`select c, count(c) from <your table name> group by c`